# «Habla español donde quieras» o «Habla español dónde quieras»

Tags: acentuación, adverbios, locuciones

Acabo de ver este texto [«Habla español dónde quieras»] en el portal internético del Instituto Cervantes. Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿va el «donde» con acento ortográfico? Creo que funge como parte de una locución subordinada adverbial de lugar y me suena a que NO es tónico en este entorno («**Ha**bla espa**ñol** donde**quie**ras»), por lo que, a mi entender, no debería tener tilde en «donde». ¿Qué creen?

Comment: Así a bote pronto yo diría que no debe llevarla. ¿Algún enlace directo al texto que comentas?

Comment: Carlos, gracias por responder. El texto original lo he perdido puesto que lo observé durante una de esas ojeadas casuales a Twitter y no sé dónde está con exactitud. Y sí, fue en el Twitter del IC, no en su portal internético oficial. Pero no fue un tuit de algún usuario, sino un tuit oficial del IC. Por eso más que nada me pareció curioso.

Comment: Cuando escribes un [tuit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asqoMGb) es muy común hacerlo desde tu móvil, así que es muy probable que el autocorrector le haya jugado una mala pasada al que lo escribió. Y como los tuits no se pueden editar...

Comment: Puede que haya sido eso. Gracias nuevamente por ayudarme con mi duda, Carlos. :-)

Comment: ¡Un placer! :-)

Comment: ¡Mil gracias, Carlos!

Comment: +1 "Portal internético"

Answer (score 7):

Tal y como expresas en tu pregunta, la forma correcta en este caso sería *donde*, sin tilde, por los motivos que tú mismo comentas.

Otra cosa, tras lo hablado en los comentarios, es que el texto provenga de un [tuit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asqoMGb) escrito desde un móvil, y el autocorrector le haya jugado una mala pasada al *community manager* de la cuenta del Instituto Cervantes.

Answer (score 5):

Sin tilde, ya que no es un interrogativo indirecto, sino un pronombre relativo. Tu razonamiento sobre la tonicidad es correcto.

Answer (score 3):

Al analizar el enunciado que mencioné en mi mensaje inicial, es claro que «Habla español donde quieras» es una oración imperativa (o exhortativa) y que «donde quieras» es frase/locución/sintagma adverbial cuya función sintáctica es ser complemento circunstancial (de lugar) del verbo. Si se segmenta la oración en grupos fónicos, también notamos que en «donde quieras», «donde» es átono. Por lo tanto, a tono con lo que sugiere la Real Academia y luego de leer con detenimiento lo que se ha discutido en esta conversación, estoy convencido de que la voz «donde» en «Habla español donde quieras» no lleva acento ortográfico. Gracias a todas las personas que participaron en este pequeño “debate”.